# Browser-based local KML editor using Google Maps API: is that possible?

Tags: google-maps-api-3, kml, httpserver

I would like to leverage the increasing capabilities of Google Maps Javascript API v3 to turn my browser into a local KML editor, so that I can open a KML file, modify it by clicking and dragging features, and then save it back?

I imagine to run some local web server (a Python script, for example), and parse KML content server-side, making it available to GMaps API. Then, upon save, the server would dump the current map state back to file.

I am not a web programmer (more into desktop-oriented Python and C#), but I think it's not even necessary to create much to achieve this, but instead just to use some well-known concepts the right way, which I need some initial guidance for, specially the server-side part.

What would be good current alternatives?

Comment: Not quite what you are looking for, but the closest I have gotten: http://www.geocodezip.com/blitz-gmap-editor/test5.html

Comment: @geocodezip Lots of ideas... Thanks for your link!